# Slow compile time - Xcode 6.x

Tags: swift, xcode6

I inherited a project with 180+ swift files, a static lib (obj-c), 20 storyboards (up to 5 screens in each view) and around 100 assets.

I use Xcode 6.1.1

It takes 2-3 seconds for each swift file to compile.

Any recommendations how to speed things up?

Comment: Download Xcode 6.3 beta. Of course at first your code won't compile at all, but after you update it, it should compile much faster.

Comment: @matt thanks. I read the release notes for 6.3 and they promise improvement. I don't wish to use a beta version for production.

Comment: Use a custom build system: http://roopc.net/posts/2014/speeding-up-swift-builds/

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of steps that I found to improve the build time:

1. Swift compiler  (code generation) - set optimization level to -O
2. Build Options - set Debug information format to DWARF. There is no need to generate dSYM overtime.

I'm still searching the code for other elements that may increase the build time e.g. assigning data to a two dimension array in one bulk.